# For any smooth manifold, is it true that for any two points on the manifold, there exists a chart that covers the two points?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Some say that we can connect two points with a continuous curve and a small contractible neighborhood of the path together with the charts of the points can be regarded as the chart. But I don't know how to verify this statement.

Comment: I remember it was well-explained in Differential Topology by Guillemin&Pollack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A connected smooth manifold $M$ has "$n$-transitive automorphism group" - this means that, for any set of $n$ distinct points $x_i$, and any set of $n$ distinct points $y_i$, there is a diffeomorphism $\varphi$ with $\varphi(x_i) = y_i$.

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are your two points, pick a small chart around $x_1$; pick $y_1 = x_1$ and $y_2$ to be some point in the chart around $x_1$. If $(U,\psi)$ is the chart around $x_1$, then your desired chart is $(\varphi^{-1}(U),\psi \circ\varphi)$.

An alternate approach finds a smooth embedded path from $x_1$ to $x_2$ and takes a tubular neighborhood. To be precise: find such an embedded path and slightly extend it to a path $(-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon) \to M$ with $\gamma(0) = x_1$, $\gamma(1) = x_2$. The tubular neighborhood theorem says that there is an open neighborhood of this path diffeomorphic to the total space of its normal bundle; the only vector bundle over an interval is trivial, so the tubular neighborhood theorem says that a neighborhood of this path is diffeomorphic to $(-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon) \times \Bbb R^{n-1}$, giving us the desired chart.

Comment: The first approach is quite clear. But I don't understand why M must have "n-transitive automorphism group". Could you please explain that for me?

Comment: @DavidWan: This is a nice exercise, which I would rather not write down here. Here are two hints. 1) First, see if you can reduce the problem to proving that on a (not necessarily compact) connected manifold without boundary, given any two points $x$ and $y$, there is a *compactly supported* diffeomorphism taking $x$ to $y$, where compactly supported means it's the identity outside of a compact set. 2) To do that, try to show that the set of points you can reach via a compactly supported diffeomorphism partitions the manifold into open equivalence classes, and conclude from connectedness.

Comment: I understand this now! I have another related question here: now suppose the manifold has a flat connection $\nabla$, then does there exist an affine chart that covers given two points? Here an affine chart $(U;x^i)$ satisfies:$\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j=0$ for any $i$ and $j$.

Comment: @DavidWan Now you're asking the tough questions... For a flat connection, the answer should be yes; it's certainly true for flat Riemannian manifolds (because I know what they all are). I think you can try to use the developing map to pick charts, but the flavor of such a result will be very different than what's in my answer. (If you did not have the flatness condition, the answer would be no: pick a Riemannian manifold and the Levi-Civita connection on it such that the manifold had diameter more than twice the injectivity radius at any point.)

Comment: I didn't expect this to be so tough. Do you have any reference for the developing map?

Comment: The statement "A connected smooth manifold $M$ has $n$-transitive automorphism group for any $n$" is true only if $M$ has dimension at least 2. Certainly, no homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ can send $0,1,2$ onto $0,2,1$.