# Smooth map with no critical point

Tags: differential-geometry, compact-manifolds

We know that given a manifold $M$ that is connected and compact, there exist a real function with a finite number of critical points, and with at least two.

Now if we consider a point $x\in M$, is it true that there exists a function $f:M\setminus \{x\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with no critical points?

If we take M to be a sphere of dimension n, I think it holds, because if we remove a point, what is left is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that we compose this diffeomorphism with a function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with no critical points, like the sum of the components?

Is it true in the general case? I think not, but is there a necessary and sufficient condition for this to hold?

Edit: 
The same way, we get that $M\setminus \{x\}$ having an atlas with only one chart is a sufficient condition, since this is what happen for the sphere (or maybe : $M$ having a chart with domain $M\setminus \{x\}$ for any $x$ could be a better statement ?). I heard that this was a necessary condition, but I have no idea whether it is true, or why.

Comment: Sorry if I across a bit snarky in my previous comment. Welcome to the site, and thanks for editing this quesiton!

Comment: If you exclude degenerate critical points, then you can probably get constraints on the manifold using Morse theory. See Theorem 3.2 in *Morse theory* by John Milnor.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I did not take it the wrong way, it was my mistake, thank you for pointing that to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Given any finite subset $F$ of a connected smooth $m$-manifold $M$, there exists a compact subset $D\subset M$ containing $F$ and diffeomorphic to the closed disk $D^m$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818513/for-any-smooth-manifold-is-it-true-that-for-any-two-points-on-the-manifold-the) for the case of 2-point subsets. Next, prove that $M-D$ is diffeomorphic to $M-\{x\}$, for any $x\in M$. Now, take $F$ to be the critical set of a smooth function $f: M\to {\mathbb R}$ and consider the restriction $f|_{M-D}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for theses explanations. I was able to show all these points, except for the fact that $M\setminus D$ is diffeomorphic to $M\setminus \{x\}$. In fact, I have already seen this result being used to compute fundamental groups of spaces with a point removed, and I can picture why it will work, for example for $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, the diffeomorphism is easy to write. However, I wonder how to prove it in a proper way for any $M$

Comment: @Van: Hint: Given the closed unit ball $D^n\subset R^n$, construct a diffeomorphism $R^n- D^n \to R^n -\{0\}$ which is the identity map outside of a larger ball $r D^n$, $r>1$. Now, use this construction to find a diffeomorphism $M-D\to M-\{x\}$, where $x$ is the "center" of $D$.

Comment: I managed to do this, thanks again.